# Formatting output from Postgres query in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, timescaledb

I am querying a large amount of data from a TimescaleDB (a Postgres DB plugin) and downsampling the result using LTTB. I am using [pg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg) for connecting and querying and [downsample](https://www.npmjs.com/package/downsample) for downsampling the data. I am running this on a Lambda and my Postgres DB in on an EC2 instance.

Here is my code:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const {Client} = require('pg'); //  Needs the nodePostgres Lambda Layer
const LTTB = require("downsample").LTTB;
const numPointsInDownsampledData = 300;


exports.handler = async (event) => {

let response = {};

console.log(JSON.stringify(event));

const client = new Client();

const deviceId = event.deviceId;
const fromDate = event.fromDate;
const toDate = event.toDate;
const column = event.column;

if (!deviceId) { // if we do not have a device id, just bail.
    return response = {
        statusCode: 400,
        body: "No device Id",
    };
}


try {
    await client.connect();
    let data = await getData(deviceId, fromDate, toDate, client, column);


    console.log(data.length);

    response = {
        count: data.length,
        data: data
    };
} catch (e) {
    response = {
        statusCode: 500,
        result: "Error: " + e
    };
} finally {
    client.end();
}

return response;
};



async function getData(deviceId, fromDate, toDate,client, column) {

const dataQuery = getQuery(deviceId, fromDate, toDate, column);
const queryResult = await client.query(dataQuery);
const data = queryResult.rows;
console.log("Full data length: "+data.length);
if(data.length > 300){
    const formattedData = [];
    data.forEach(function (dataItem) {
        formattedData.push({ x: dataItem.time_stamp, y: getColumn(column, dataItem)});
    });
    return LTTB(formattedData, numPointsInDownsampledData);
}else {
    return data;
}
}

function getColumn(column, dataItem) {
switch (column){
    case "i1":                  return dataItem.i1;
    case "i2":                  return dataItem.i2;
    case "i3":                  return dataItem.i3;
    case "i4":                  return dataItem.i4;
    case "i5":                  return dataItem.i5;
    case "i6":                  return dataItem.i6;
    case "i7":                  return dataItem.i7;
    case "i8":                  return dataItem.i8;
    case "mrt":                 return dataItem.mrt;
    case "air_temperature":     return dataItem.air_temperature;
    case "humidity":            return dataItem.humidity;
    case "tvoc":                return dataItem.tvoc;
    case "co2":                 return dataItem.co2;
    case "sitting_mrt":         return dataItem.sitting_mrt;
    case "standing_mrt":        return dataItem.standing_mrt;

}
}


function getQuery(deviceId, fromDate, toDate, column) {
return `SELECT time_stamp,${column}  FROM sensor_data_v2 WHERE device_id = '${deviceId}' and 
                                        time_stamp between '${fromDate}' and '${toDate}';`;
 }
```

The [downsample](https://www.npmjs.com/package/downsample) package needs the input array of objects formatted as follows:

```
{ x: new Date(), y: 152.2 };
```

So, I am having to loop through the result of the query and format the data so [downsample](https://www.npmjs.com/package/downsample) will be happy with it.  As you can imagine, looping through a large amount of data can take a while and I can potentially have 3 to 5 million rows in the result.

Questions:

1. Is there some way I can format the query result in the format that [downsample](https://www.npmjs.com/package/downsample) will be happy with. Not attached to the [pg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg) package, happy to use another one if it has the functionality that I need.
2. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Simplify `getColumn` to `return dataItem[column]` (and just inline that expression)?

Comment: You can `SELECT time_stamp as x, ${column} as y` to avoid the postprocessing, but I doubt the looping is your problem - it is transferring those many items from the database to the lambda.

Comment: Thanks for those, ill give them a try :)
Do you have any suggestions on how I could implement this better? Maybe a NodeJS app running in the EC2 instance that is hosting the TimecaleDB to eliminate the transfer time? 
I would prefer to run this on a Lambda but if that is not going to work, I am happy to implement other solutions

Comment: Another solution to try would be implementing the LTTB algorithm in SQL (or PL/PGSQL) natively. Judging from the thesis, it's not that complicated.

Comment: Not familiar with PL/PGSQL. I'll look into it, thank you.